# Can the same thing be said as both an imperative sentence and an interrogative sentence?

Tags: interrogatives, imperative-sentences

"Guess what it is going to be next."

"Guess what is it going to be next?"

Do both the sentences express the same thing i.e. asking or instructing the listener to guess?

Comment: "Guess what it is going to be next?" doesn't really work as a question in English, idiomatically.  We would say something like *Can you guess what it is going to be next?*

Comment: In spoken English we do say:  "Guess what is going to be next?" And it can also be an imperative.

Comment: Can you say the same thing in different moods? Yes. BTW, you're not supposed to ask yes/no questions. Have you taken the tour?

Answer (score 0):

Your example sentence does not work as an interrogative sentence. There are other sentences, however, that can work that way:

> You're going shopping.

> You're going shopping?

The first is a statement of fact. The second is a question identified by punctuation in writing and vocal inflection in speech. The question may be equivalent to "Are you going shopping?" or it may be interpreted as communicating incredulity, like "Are you **really** going shopping? Now?" The specific meaning would depend on context.

In informal speech, one might also hear interrogatives formed by omitting the helping verb:

> She left him? (for "Did she leave him?")

These may also function as declarative sentences:

> She left him.

Just know that the interrogative form is non-standard, informal speech.